# Question regarding cardinality of differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give an example of a set $A = \{ 1,2,...k \}$ for a smallest $k \in \mathbb{N} $ containing subsets $A_1, A_2, A_3$ such that $ |A_i - A_j| = |A_j - A_i | = |i-j|$ for every two integers $i$ and $j$ with $ 1 \leq i < j \leq 3 $.

Is it correct if you say $k=4$ with $A_1 = \{1,2\}, A_2 = \{2,3\}, A_3 = \{3,4\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your example is good ($k = 4$ is minimal).
To see this:

- The condition  $|A_i - A_j| = |A_j - A_i|$ implies that $|A_i| = |A_j|$. Also, all the $A_i$ must be proper non-empty subsets (otherwise some of your conditions are not satisfied).
- For $k = 1,2,3$, it's easy to see that the remarks in the previous  point imply that some other condition is not satisfied.